# Counting characters in ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, cursor, fields-attributes

can somebody tell me how can i count character in a field either using field calculator or cursor.

i tried the below code :

```
import arcpy

inputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
InputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
expression = "len(!" + InputField + "!)"

arcpy.AddField_management(inputFeatureClass,"CountChr","SHORT")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputFeatureClass,"CountChr",expression,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

but result is null.

i tried cursor :

```
import arcpy

#taking input from user

    inputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    InputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    arcpy.AddField_management(inputFeatureClass,"CountChr","SHORT")

    cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (inputFeatureClass, [InputField, "CountChr"])
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = len(row[0])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    del cursor
```

but result is again null

can somebody tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Is your input field a text field and your count field a numeric field?

Comment: Yes InputField is a text field, and i am adding a a new field name "Countchr" and counting characters in it from InputField(see code)

Comment: What's the field type for the field "Countchr"?

Comment: Wrong spatial extent could be a reason for weird fc behavior

Comment: perhaps wrongly, but i often start throwing in print() statements to debug - what do you get if you print row[0] to the screen (or write to a file if there are too many rows to print to screen)?

Comment: What type of fields are you working with in your fields (e.g. text, short, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

If you have some values that are null, that may be causing the issue. Try using the following codeblock in the field calculator:

```
def length(field):
    return len(field) if field else 0
```

and

```
CountChr = length(!yourFieldName!)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the field name behind the input field parameter before converting the expression variable to a string.  Otherwise the field name passed to calculate field will simply be "len (!InputField!) instead of the actual field name for that parameter.  Try changing

```
expression = "len(!" + InputField + "!)"
```

to

```
expression = "len(!{0}!)".format(InputField)
```